# Understanding what switch statement takes

Tags: c, switch-statement

So I came up with an idea to create a calculator that converts Binary Hexadecimal and Decimal Numbers, so after a short break to remember how to convert I started my code in c and this is where I got stucked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NULL ((char *)0)

int main() {
    printf("Please choose one of the options:\n"
       "for hexadecimal to binary enter xb\n"
       "for binary to hexadecimal enter bx\n"
       "for binary to decimal enter bd\n"
       "for hexadecimal to decimal enter xd\n"
       "for decimal to binary enter db\n"
       "for decimal to hexadecimal enter dx\n");
    char * input_user;
    input_user = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    scanf("%s2", input_user);
    printf("%s", input_user);
    switch (input_user) {
        case xd: 
                printf("something");
                break;
        default:
               printf("nothing");
               break; 
    }
    free(input_user);
}
```

when I pass the pointer to the switch it sends me an error

`Statement requires expression of integer type ('char *' is invalid)`

now I don't get why when I pass `input_user` it throws me that error however if I pass `* input_user` it silences the error, Isn't input_user same as * input_user due to as I declared it?

(please keep in mind that I am new to this platform so I don't know properly how to write a question here)

I tried to read more about switch in other websites but yet not found a good explanation

Comment: What do these     scanf("%s2", input_user);
    printf("%s", input_user); mean?

Comment: try `char* input_user` or `char *input_user`

Comment: You have only allocated two bytes of memory, so the string input can be **one byte** only. Assuming `scanf("%s2", input_user);` was supposed to be `scanf("%2s", input_user);` that will still break the buffer. Always use a generous buffer for user input.

Comment: @aronb how can it help?

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't `input_user` same as `* input_user` due to as I declared it?

No. `* input_user` only references the first `char` of the allocated memory - a `char`, something suitable for `switch`.  `input_user` is a pointer - not suitable for `switch`.

---

- To read in a string of length 2, code needs a buffer of size 3 to store the first 2 letters and a *null character*.  Casting is not needed.  Define the object and initialize in one step.  `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so `sizeof(char) *` is not needed.  If wanting to note the size, size to the referenced object, not the type.  Not shown for brevity: check allocation success.

```
// char * input_user;
// input_user = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
char * input_user = malloc(3);
// or
char * input_user = malloc(sizeof input_user[0] * 3);
```

- To scan user input into a string use `%s` **always** with a *width limit* (the max number of characters to read).  Check the return value and compare against the expected value.

```
// scanf("%s2", input_user);
if (scanf("%2s", input_user) != 1) TBD_Code_to_report_error();
```

- Code cannot switch on a string.  Switch on an integer such as a single `char`

```
    // First character
    switch (input_user[0]) {
        case 'x': printf(" hex"); break;
        case 'd': printf(" dec"); break;
        case 'b': printf(" bin"); break;
        default:  printf(" ???");
    }

    printf(" to");

    // Next character
    switch (input_user[1]) {
        case 'x': printf(" hex"); break;
        case 'd': printf(" dec"); break;
        case 'b': printf(" bin"); break;
        default:  printf(" ???");
    }

    printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `char * input_user;` is a
   pointer. `switch(x)` requires an integer value.
2. You can't choose from the strings in the `switch` as `==` does not compare strings contents only references (addresses). You need to use `strcmp` function to compare them and `if` statements

```
if(!strcmp(input_user, "yes")) {/* do something for `yes` */}
else if(!strcmp(input_user, "no")) {/* do something for 'no` */}
else if(!strcmp(input_user, "maybe")) {/* do something for `maybe` */}
/* ... */
```

You may want to switch from the first character of string

```
switch(*input_string)
{
    case 'y'
    case 'Y'
       /* do something for 'y' */
       break;
    case 'n'
    case 'N'
       /* do something for 'n' */
       break;

    /* more cases */

    default:
       /* do something for everything elese */
       break
}
```

3. Do not define `NULL` yourself. Included headers define it.

You can use switch case on pointers on some occasions (for example in embedded development)

```
int enableClock(GPIO_TypeDef *gpio)
{
    int result = 0;
    switch((uint32_t)gpio)
    {
        case GPIOA:
            __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
            break;
        case GPIOB:
            __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
            break;
        case GPIOC:
            __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
            break;
        /* ... */
        default:
            result = 1;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, where the information is contained in only two bytes, it's possible to use a macro to combine that pair, both from the user's input and as constant values suitable to use with `switch/case`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PAIR(x,y) ( ((x)<<8) | (y) )

int main( void ) {
    char sel[ 100 ];

    for( ;; ) {
        do {
            printf("\nPlease choose one of the options:\n"
                "xb - hexadecimal to binary\n"
                "bx - binary to hexadecimal\n"
                "bd - binary to decimal\n"
                "db - decimal to binary\n"
                "xd - hexadecimal to decimal\n"
                "dx - decimal to hexadecimal\n");

        } while( scanf( "%99s", sel ) != 1 );
        puts( sel );

        switch( PAIR( sel[0], sel[1] ) ) {
            case PAIR( 'x', 'd' ):
                puts( "hex to dec" );
                break;
            case PAIR( 'd', 'x' ):
                puts( "dec to hex" );
                break;

            /* more options */

            default:
                puts( "nonsense" );
                break; 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the reformatting of the menu options. Don't make your users struggle!